# Where is the R-computing mistake?

Tags: r, vector

```
> num.1.2[2*2^1/3 - 1/2 - (-1)^1/6]
numeric(0)
> 2*2^1/3 - 1/2 - (-1)^1/6
[1] 1
> num.1.2[1]
[1] 1
```

Where is the mistake? I don't see it.

Comment: There is probably a floating point rounding issue.  Try: `num.1.2[round(2*2^1/3 - 1/2 - (-1)^1/6)]`

Comment: `2*2^1/3 - 1/2 - (-1)^1/6` is not exactly equal to 1 when you use floating point math. If you want to index your vector, be sure to make sure that index is an integer. Perhaps use `round()` is that's appropriate for your calculations. A longer discussion of the issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal